# nill attribute with nillable complexType

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, soap-client, complextype

I'm experiencing problems with creating a `PHP Soap Request` using classes. Below a part of the WSDL.

```
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Bars" type="tns:ArrayOfBars"/>

<s:complexType name="ArrayOfBars">
    <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Bar" nillable="true" type="tns:Bar"/>
    </s:sequence>
</s:complexType>

<s:complexType name="Bar">
    <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Name" type="s:string"/>
        ... --more elements-- ...
    </s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
```

Below the class

```
class Foo
{
    public $Bars;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->Bars = array();
    }
}

class Bar
{
    public $Name;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->Name = null;
    }
}
```

How can I create the request below? As far as I know it is a valid request, because the `Bar` element is nillable.

```
<ns1:Foo>
        <ns1:Bars>
            <ns1:Bar xsi:nil="true"/>
        </ns1:Bars>
<ns1:Foo>
```

When I change the `Bars` property to `array(null)`, I get the error `Object reference not an instance of an object.`.  When I change it to `array(new Bar())`, it must be a full, valid, `Bar` object.

Comment: Addition: as said, when I send the Bar with nil property i got the error Object reference not an instance of an object. The faultcode is soap:Server, so it might be a problem of the soap server?

Comment: I have a similar problem, but not with complex types but with simple int value. I want to create nullable int in PHP, which does not work. I use `new SoapVar(null, XSD_INT, "int", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"`, but this does not add `xsi:nil="true"` to my request. Did you manage to get simple types working?

I think you could try something like `new SoapVar($bar, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT)`.